# Change the CRS in R, but the current CRS is not clear

Tags: coordinate-system, r, switzerland

I have a set of datasets that looks like this called ch

| municipality | BIP(CHF) | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55'000 | 2486904 | 1112086 |
| 2 | 76'000 | 2486907 | 1112001 |
| 3 | 89'000 | 2487005 | 1112178 |
| 4 | 45'000 | 2488520 | 1112113 |
| 5 | 77'000 | 2488696 | 1116564 |
| 6 | 78'000 | 2488701 | 1112961 |

It is not given which CRS x and y have. I found through a CRS transformer that they are in LV95, but I would like to change them in LV03.

I could not find a good code for change them that I have this output, but with geometry in CRS lv03

| municipality | BIP(CHF) | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55'000 | c(486904.777, 112085.881) |
| 2 | 76'000 | c(486907.780, 112000.881) |
| 3 | 89'000 | c(487005.778, 112177.882) |
| 4 | 45'000 | c(488520.794, 112112.873) |
| 5 | 77'000 | c(488696.721, 116563.815) |
| 6 | 78'000 | c(488701.798, 112960.870) |

Comment: What country is this coordinate system used in?

Comment: Switzerland. The dataset for x and y is in lv95 but I would like to change it in lv03

Comment: How did you get the second table? Are those the same things as in the first table but in LV03? Do you know the EPSG code or the WKT specification for LV95 and LV03?

Comment: yes, the same things like in the first table but in lv03

Comment: How did you create those or were you given them and you want to know how to reproduce that?

Comment: i calculate in on the internet cordinate transformer, but the dataset is larger, so manually is uncomfortable

Comment: code 21781 is for Lv03

Comment: code 2056 is for LV95

Comment: I couldn't find a code for r because i am very new in r and spatial data science

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into the basics of the `sf` package for spatial data and then its a case of using `st_transform`.

Example/proof of concept: First lets create a sample point. Your LV95 coordinate system appears to be EPSG code 2056 (https://epsg.io/2056)

```
> p = st_sfc(st_point(c(2486904, 1112086)), crs=2056)
> p
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2486904 ymin: 1112086 xmax: 2486904 ymax: 1112086
Projected CRS: CH1903+ / LV95
POINT (2486904 1112086)
```

LV03 coordinates appear to be epsg code 21781 (https://epsg.io/21781) so you can use `st_transform`:

```
> st_transform(p, 21781)
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 486904 ymin: 112086 xmax: 486904 ymax: 112086
Projected CRS: CH1903 / LV03
POINT (486904 112086)
```

which seems close to your example, at least to the nearest meter.

The `sf` package lets you create spatial dataframes and `st_transform` works on those too. You probably need `st_as_sf` with some parameters to turn a data frame to a spatial data frame but you should find an intro to `sf` for spatial data and you'll learn a lot more than if we just spoonfeed you the answer here!