# Merge dataset and shapefile to calculate mean ses in r

Tags: r

I have a shapefile with 106 regions of switzerland
and a dataset which is very large, so it is not possible to show it, otherwise it is not clear :

I read it on R both datasets

```
Library(readr)
ms_shp <- st_read("CH.shp")
ssep <- read_csv("sesch.csv")
```

both have geometries. in the shapefile it is called geometry and the crs system is LV03 , EPSG:21781 and also xy is the geometry for the dataset which is also in crs LV03.

The first 5 rows of the dataset ssep looks like this:

| gis | ssep | xy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 73 | c(486216, 111388) |
| 2 | 73 | c(486221, 111410.999999997) |
| 3 | 73 | c(486263, 111523.999999996) |
| 4 | 73 | c(486267, 111530.000000001) |
| 5 | 73 | c(486296, 111579.999999996) |

Now I would like to now which gisid lie on which regions in the shapefile and then calculate the ssep of the shapefile.

I used that code

```
library(sp)
pt.in.poly <- sp::over(ms_shp, ssep, fn = mean)
```

I thought it give me an index of the gisid but I got this error message. and I used mean, because I thought it calculate ssep mean

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : can't find inherited method for function 'over' for signature '"sf", "spec_tbl_df"'.
```

Comment: Is this related? Are you working on the same problem? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436134/change-the-crs-in-r-but-the-current-crs-is-not-clear

Comment: no, I don't think so. I search which gisid lie on which regions. i don't have problems with crs system

Comment: the crs system is for both datasets the same in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used `st_read` which creates `sf` objects but then tried `sp::over` which works with the older `sp` classes.

You need to use functions from the `sf` package, such as `st_intersects`, to look at the relationship between points and polygons. You'll probably also have to make `ssep` into an sf points spatial dataframe - that xy column with values like `c(1234,5678)` looks a bit odd.

Let's work this out. First read the CSV using base `read.csv`, since that interprets the comma in the coordinate string column as a separator and neatly splits the string for us.

```
> ssep = read.csv("./ssepch.csv")

> head(ssep)
  X    gisid    ssep3                 xy
1 1 73.29197 c(486216            111388)
2 2 73.29197 c(486221  111410.999999997)
3 3 73.29197 c(486263  111523.999999996)
4 4 73.29197 c(486267  111530.000000001)
```

Then we can get the x and y coords by substituting the stray chunks of code from the strings and converting to numeric:

```
> ssep$x = as.numeric(sub("c\\(","", ssep$ssep3))
> ssep$y = as.numeric(sub("\\)","", ssep$xy))
> head(ssep)
  X    gisid    ssep3                 xy      x      y
1 1 73.29197 c(486216            111388) 486216 111388
2 2 73.29197 c(486221  111410.999999997) 486221 111411
3 3 73.29197 c(486263  111523.999999996) 486263 111524
4 4 73.29197 c(486267  111530.000000001) 486267 111530
5 5 73.29197 c(486296  111579.999999996) 486296 111580
6 6 73.96802 c(486343  111490.999999999) 486343 111491
```

Now make an sf points data frame:

```
> ssep = st_as_sf(ssep, coords=c("x","y"), crs=21781)
> head(ssep)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 486216 ymin: 111388 xmax: 486343 ymax: 111580
Projected CRS: CH1903 / LV03
  X    gisid    ssep3                 xy              geometry
1 1 73.29197 c(486216            111388) POINT (486216 111388)
2 2 73.29197 c(486221  111410.999999997) POINT (486221 111411)
3 3 73.29197 c(486263  111523.999999996) POINT (486263 111524)
4 4 73.29197 c(486267  111530.000000001) POINT (486267 111530)
```

Now that's an sf points data frame. You should now be able to do:

```
st_intersects(ssep, ms_shp)
```

and get a list of polygons that each point is in. You've only shared the .shp part of the shapefile so I can't do that on your data right now.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137849/discussion-on-answer-by-spacedman-merge-dataset-and-shapefile-to-calculate-mean).